# VSCode change aux directory of latex workshop

Tags: visual-studio-code, tex

My current config is the following:

```
  "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [{
    "name": "texify",
    "command": "texify",
    "args": [
      "--synctex",
      "--pdf",
      "--tex-option=\"-interaction=nonstopmode\"",
      "--tex-option=\"-file-line-error\"",
      "%DOC%.tex"
    ],
      "env": {}
  }
]
```

However, I am trying to put all the files that are generated, which aren't the output pdf (so .aux and .log for now), somewhere else so it doesn't fill up everything. I don't care if it's a subfolder, or one folder for all project. How can I do this?

Comment: For having the auxiliary files in a separate folder I would use ltx2any (https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any) Without this, you will need to configure each and every tool separately (bibtex...).

Comment: Relates to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525604/save-auxiliary-latex-files-in-another-folder-in-vsc) from tex.stackexchange. Looks like it is not recommended.

Comment: Depending on your operating system and the available command lines, you could try instructing the LaTeX WorkShop extension to invoke a series of bash/cmd commands. You could `cd` into your preferred build folder. Then run `texify path/to/file.tex`. Then, cd it back to your original folder. Also, please consider that Texify has a lot of issues with BibLaTeX and Biber.

Answer (score 1):

You probably moved on from your question but for others with this question, I have found the answer here:

https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-tools

Basically, add this to your settings.json:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "<Name of your output dir>"
```

(Note: It will include the .pdf file there too)

Comment: This is not a correct answer because the only thing you are doing is defining the `%OUTDIR%` variable.